# Make content of shared memory null if its pointer is null c++

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, shared-memory

There're struct (Type) and function, that allow to work with struct through shared memory (shm_open and mmap) returns Type*.

```
Type* type = openSharedMemory();
```

I want to make content if shared memory null and statement `typeptr == nullptr` should returns true in the process which not create but openSharedMemory memory.
Is it possible?

Comment: or in c++11 `type = nullptr`. Though smart pointers would be even better. There you can also call `.reset()`

Comment: @KlasLindbäck it has no effect. type == NULL is false in this case.

Comment: @Hayt Not clear at all that a smart pointer is needed here.

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah it depends if it is an owning pointer or not. Just wanted to make aware of the existence of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how pointers work.

If you set a pointer to null the memory still stays there until someone changes it. Even if there is a 0 in the memory this can also just mean an integer 0 for example. This is true for normal pointers in c++ but also for shared memory.

What you need to do is make the memory "invalid". There is no standard to do this in c++ so this has to be defined by yourself.

You have several options here.

---

One is to define an invalid value for yourself and set the data to this value.

E.g. if you have an `int` but you know you only store positive numbers in there you can set it to `-1` to mark as invalid (or maximum/minimum int, I guess you get the point).

And then you check that instead of the pointer

```
//in some header
static const int INVALID_VALUE = -1;

//some process
type->shared_int = INVALID_VALUE;

//somewhere else
if(type->shared_int != INVALID_VALUE) //or whatever
    //do stuff
```

---

If you have a custom struct in your memory you can add a boolean flag whether it is valid or not

```
struct Type
{
    bool valid = true; //c++11 initialize to true
    //other data members
};
```

When you now want to mark the memory as invalid just set the member to false and check for that.

```
//some process
type->valid = false;

//somewhere else
if(type->valid)
    //do stuff
```

---

You can avoid those things if you have clear ownership of the objects when you are using normal pointers.

In interprocess communication that can get a bit complicated so you have to use mechanisms like this.

Design wise it would be better to have one process who is responsible for the memory (allocation and deallocation) and make sure that other process are done or just stop needing to access the memory when you "delete" it. But this is not always possible though.

Comment: Thank you, I thing it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm not mistaken it's useless do delete(typeptr) because I didn't alocate if with new()

Not merely useless, but very likely undefined behaviour. If you're lucky the program would crash.

> Is it possible to make typeptr nullptr?

Yes. You can assign the value:

```
typeptr = nullptr;
```

> It works only in the same process, where I create shared memory.

Each process have their own memory, where objects like `typeptr` live. No other process have access to these objects. Setting one pointer to null doesn't affect any other pointer.

Indeed, if the pointer that you want to set null is in the process that created the shared memory, then only that process has access to the pointer and therefore that process must set the value... Unless the pointer itself is in another shared memory block, which I assume isn't the case.

> I want to make content if shared memory null

Ah, setting pointed content to null is completely different from setting the pointer null. You can set the shared memory to all zeroes using `std::memset`. Just like you would with non-shared memory.

Comment: It works only in the same process, where I create shared memory. I also need to check it in process which openSharedMemory this memory.

Comment: @Padmelina: That's not how pointers work.

Comment: @user2079303 So I have different pointers, that can only make me works with data in shared memory? If I null pointers in create process in openSharedMemory process I can only are that all data is 0?

Comment: So I have different pointers, that can only make me works with data in shared memory? If I null pointers in create process in open process I can only are that all filds are 0?

Comment: @Padmelina sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase?